# How can I install the alias command?

Tags: 12.04, installation, executable, alias

My Ubuntu installation does not have the `alias` command. Usually it would be in `/usr/bin` along with other basic commands like `which`. I can type:

```
which which
/usr/bin/which
```

but

```
which alias
```

interesting that it doesn't say `alias` not found; other Linuxes would say that.

I ran

```
sudo find / -name "alias" -print
```

and this did not find it either.

Could a kind person please tell me how to install alias? I tried `sudo apt-get install alias` but this did not work.

Answer (score 2):

`alias` is actually built in to your shell environment (which is `bash` by default). To learn more about it, run `man bash` and then search for the `alias` builtin by typing `/alias<ENTER>`. (`/` to tell `man` to search again).

A few tidbits I have come to learn about `alias`:

- To run a command in its original form, run `\command`
- Aliases do not work in shell scripts
- Functions are preferred to aliases in most cases due to the higher flexability, but aliases are still useful for simple renames or common switches
- Add your aliases to the end of your `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.zshrc`, or whatever)

Answer (score 1):

To make an alias just add the following line at the end of `~/.bashrc`

```
alias <commcnd>='/path/to/executable'
```

Or,

```
alias <command>='some command -option'
```

For example to use `rm -i` as an alias say,`rr`, just add the following line at the end of `~/.bashrc`

```
alias rr='rm -i'
```

Next run the following in terminal,

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now onwards when you run `rr filename` it will implied as `rm -i filename`

To know if you set an alias try the following in terminal,

```
type rr
```

Output will be like,

```
rr is aliased to `rm -i'
```

Hope these would help.

Comment: Alternately you can also put aliases inside `~/.bash_aliases`. If you do so you need to source it.

Comment: @Mimi do you have any further query? Let me know.